# Bought Apple Watch Series 4 Cellular from US, will it work in India?

Tags: apple-watch

Did I make a mistake? Is there any way to start using cellular feature in India with US watch model?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you made a mistake I'm afraid. The Americas-regional model of the Apple Watch 4 won't work in India. For that you'll need the Europa/Asia/Pacific-regional model.

In addition to that you'll need a supported carrier in order to get an eSIM for the watch. In India this is only supported with [Airtel](https://www.airtel.in/onlinestore/apple-watch-series-4) and [Jio](https://www.jio.com/en-in/apple-watch-4). For details refer to Apple Watch Carriers webpage and search for *India*:

- https://www.apple.com/in/watch/cellular/